# Restrict market updates to WiFi network

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi, application-autoupdate

In order to save some volume on my data plan, I'd like to limit updates from the market to the times when I'm connected to a WiFi. And as every good geek, I want this to be automated, in other words, if I am connected to a WiFi network, check and install updates from the market (for those apps that I allow to automatically update). Is there a way of doing this?

I'm running Android 2.2 on an HTC Desire. If it helps, I have Tasker installed.

Update: I don't want to change the autosync settings.

Update II: I'm not rooted and am looking for a "stock" solution.

Comment: I assume you want AutoSync to remain enabled while you're on EDGE / 3G? Else, it'd be a simple matter to enable WiFi and Autosync.

Comment: Are you rooted? Does Tasker have the capability to kill services? If so, killing the Market service while on mobile data will eliminate New Updates Available notifications. Once you're on WiFi, starting the Market service should then enable auto-update of apps.

Don't use Tasker, so not sure if it can perform in this manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new version of the Market app allows you to limit updates to Wi-Fi only, among some other new features, like defaulting all apps to auto-update (if the app supports it).

[Android Police has a write-up](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/01/download-android-market-3-3-11-adds-new-settings-default-auto-update-update-over-wi-fi-only-shortcuts-and-more/). (They also have the apk you can download if you don't want to wait.)

Answer (score 4):

This will only work if you're rooted, but [DroidWall](http://code.google.com/p/droidwall/) is a really good front end for Android's iptables.  You can filter access to data based on WiFi and 3G to just about anything in your phone (including the Market) that could request it.

Comment: Note that for Market to work, you need to allow not only the Market application, but also some other downloading subsystem in DroidWall.